# How to read auth.logs in AWS ec2 instance logs?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

We were looking into this file, `/var/logs/auth.logs` and shows this:

[image]

**(Question 1:)** Is this a possible hack attempt?

Using this website https://www.abuseipdb.com/check/59.173.173.107 I can track the origin of the IP address.

I also run this command `last` and shows this:

[image]

Can anyone please tell me what are this are? Thanks! 
**(Question 2:)** What is the difference of last and auth.logs?

**(Question 3:)** What is `CRON[17637]` and `sshd[17686]`? 
**(Question 4:)** What does this line mean, `Received disconnect from 59.173.173.107: 11: Normal Shutdown, Thank you for playing [preauth]`? 
**(Question 5:)** Is this normal? Does everyone always get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) its not 
2.) `last` is more readable. `auth.logs` is the complete info of `last`. 
3.) `sshd[]` is someone who accessed your server via ssh using pem while cron is built in function by aws. 
4.) someone tried to access your server but failed and leave a note `thank you for playing`. its a bot. not a hacker. everyone received this not even in aws but other hosting site. not a hack attempt its just that. 
5.) Yup. already answered in number 4.